# Get records after a certain record in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We publish files to S3. We store the files in the following folder format:

```
year/month/day/hour/minute/second/fileName
```

When reading from this bucket, consumers can use prefix and query on daily or hourly frequency.

Is there a way in S3 to get objects that were published AFTER a particular object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon S3 [`GET BUCKET` API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) has a `marker` parameter:

> Specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a bucket. Amazon S3 returns object keys in UTF-8 binary order, starting with key after the marker in order.

Combined with the `prefix` parameter, this should be able to list the 'next object' in a particular path.

The equivalent from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) would be `list-objects`, eg:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket MY-BUCKET --prefix MY-PATH
  --starting-token KEY-TO-START-AFTER
```

(I tried it -- it works!)

Comment: For those that are wondering, S3 default sort is lexicographical order (aka alphabetical), so `start after` gets every object that is after that key alphabetically.